# How to call complex Stored Function using Entity Manager?

Tags: java, spring, oracle, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-entitymanager

I am trying to call this using JPA/Hibernate `EntityManager` bu I keep getting errors. Essentially this is a stipped-down version of a PL/SQL function.

```
 FUNCTION create_foo(f_name      VARCHAR2,
                     l_name      VARCHAR2,
                     someNum     NUMBER,
                     someResult  OUT VARCHAR) RETURN NUMBER AS
    id  NUMBER;
    someString VARCHAR2(100);

  BEGIN
    id := foo.generateID(webpassword);
    someResult := create_Result(to_char(aidm)
    -- Some other logic and stuff with someString and id
    
    RETURN id;
  END;
```

Here's what my code looks like:

```
 StoredProcedureQuery storedProcedureQuery = entityManager.createStoredProcedureQuery("schema.create_foo")
                    .registerStoredProcedureParameter("f_name", String.class, ParameterMode.IN)
                    .registerStoredProcedureParameter("l_name", String.class, ParameterMode.IN)
                    .registerStoredProcedureParameter("someNum", int.class, ParameterMode.IN)
                    .registerStoredProcedureParameter("someResult", String.class, ParameterMode.OUT)
                    .registerStoredProcedureParameter("return", int.class, ParameterMode.OUT)
                    .setParameter("f_name", "John")
                    .setParameter("l_name", "Doe")
                    .setParameter("someNum", 0);

            Object singleResult = storedProcedureQuery.execute();
```

I have tried multiple things but I can not get it to work. I have tried changing the return `ParameterMode` to `REF_CURSOR` but I got the same error
`PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'create_foo'`

If I try this code like this without `registerStoredProcedureParameter` for the return:

```
 StoredProcedureQuery storedProcedureQuery = entityManager.createStoredProcedureQuery("schema.create_foo")
                    .registerStoredProcedureParameter("f_name", String.class, ParameterMode.IN)
                    .registerStoredProcedureParameter("l_name", String.class, ParameterMode.IN)
                    .registerStoredProcedureParameter("someNum", int.class, ParameterMode.IN)
                    .registerStoredProcedureParameter("someResult", String.class, ParameterMode.OUT)
                    .setParameter("f_name", "John")
                    .setParameter("l_name", "Doe")
                    .setParameter("someNum", 0);

            Object singleResult = storedProcedureQuery.execute();
```

I get this error: `PLS-00221: 'create_foo' is not a procedure or is undefined`. I have also tried different combinations of `storedProcedureQuery.getSingleResult()` and `storedProcedureQuery.excecute()`. I am using this same process for other stored procedures and they are working great. The only difference is that this one is a function and has an `OUT` Pram and a `RETURN` whereas the other ones only have an `IN` param. This stored procedure/function is being used by other projects and is working so I know the problem is not the PL/SQL but rather my code.

**How do I get this to work?**

Comment: Is your database set to support `NUMBER` and `VARCHAR2`?  The first exception says that datatypes may be incorrect.  In PL/SQL, the `NUMBER` and `VARCHAR2` data types must be turned on in the database configuration parameter.

Comment: @skidwiz Yes the database supports ```NUMBER``` and ```VARCHAR2```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/78068922/245523