# Getting Error Wrong number or types of arguments while calling stored procedure in Oracle using Spring Data Jpa

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have Oracle PL/SQL procedure as below

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getCollectorP2PSummary(inCollectorId IN VARCHAR2)
RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
AS
p_cursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
    OPEN p_cursor FOR
    SELECT inCollectorId AS collectorId,
        COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN A.PYMT_SCHD_SUM_STATUS_IND = 'BROKEN' AND TRUNC(TO_DATE(PYMT_SCHD_SUM_STATUS_DT, 'YYYYMMDD')) BETWEEN TRUNC(SYSDATE - INTERVAL '30' DAY) AND TRUNC(SYSDATE) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0) as brokenInLast30Days,
        COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN A.PYMT_SCHD_SUM_STATUS_IND = 'ACTIVE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0) AS activePromiseToPays,
        COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN A.PYMT_SCHD_SUM_STATUS_IND = 'ACTIVE' THEN B.DLNQ_AMT ELSE 0 END), 0) as delinquencyAmount,
        COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN A.PYMT_SCHD_SUM_STATUS_IND = 'ACTIVE' THEN A.TOTAL_SCHD_PYMT_AMT ELSE 0 END), 0) as promiseToPayAmount,
        COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN A.PYMT_SCHD_SUM_STATUS_IND = 'ACTIVE' THEN A.TOTAL_SCHD_PYMT_AMT - A.total_actual_pymt_amt ELSE 0 END), 0) as remainingAmount,
        COALESCE(COUNT(CASE WHEN A.PYMT_SCHD_SUM_STATUS_IND = 'ACTIVE' AND C.pymt_schd_status_ind = 'PENDING' THEN C.pymt_schd_sum_seq END), 0) as pendingPayments
    FROM PYMT_SCHD_SUM A
    LEFT JOIN COLL_ACCT B ON A.ACCT_NBR = B.ACCT_NBR
    LEFT JOIN PYMT_SCHD C ON B.ACCT_NBR = C.ACCT_NBR
    WHERE B.CLLCTR_ID = inCollectorId;
RETURN p_cursor;
END;
```

I'm calling it with JPA as below

ManagerSummaryEntity.java

```
@NamedStoredProcedureQuery(
     name = "getManagerP2PSummary", 
     procedureName = "getManagerP2PSummary", 
     resultClasses = ManagerSummaryEntity.class, 
     parameters = {
            @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR, type = void.class),
            @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, type = String.class)
    }
)
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class ManagerSummaryEntity implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private String collectorId;
    Long brokenInLast30Days;
    Long activePromiseToPays;
    BigDecimal delinquencyAmount;
    BigDecimal promiseToPayAmount;
    BigDecimal remainingAmount;
    Long pendingPayments;
}
```

EntityManagerUtils.java

```
@Transactional
public Optional<ManagerSummaryEntity> getManagerP2PSummary(EntityManager entityManager, String collectorId) {
    try {
        StoredProcedureQuery query = entityManager.createNamedStoredProcedureQuery("getManagerP2PSummary");
        query.setParameter(2, collectorId);
        List<ManagerSummaryEntity> entities = (List<ManagerSummaryEntity>) query.getResultList();
        if (query.execute()) {
            return Optional.of(entities.get(0));
        }
        return Optional.empty();
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}
```

However, I'm getting below error:

`2023-02-07 10:09:16,284 ERROR [org.hib.eng.jdb.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (executor-thread-0) ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'GETCOLLECTORP2PSUMMARY' ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PL/SQL: Statement ignored`

Can anyone tell me how to resolve this ?

P.S: I tried passing named parameter as well, but it didn't work either.

Comment: a function is not a procedure. Have you tried to call it directly

Comment: This is more a question for Spring Data JPA than for Oracle. I don't know this product, but I would expect that somewhere it'd be evident that the REF_CURSOR type is the return value, or perhaps an OUT parameter, rather than an in-bind. Look into how you do that with Spring Data JPA.

Comment: Yes, I tried to call it directly, and it works fine, I have same function for postgres also, and when I try to call it through code, it does not give any error, the problem is only with Oracle function.

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling a function which returns a cursor, you need to add a hint "org.hibernate.callableFunction".

```
@NamedStoredProcedureQuery(
 name = "getManagerP2PSummary", 
 procedureName = "getManagerP2PSummary", 
 resultClasses = ManagerSummaryEntity.class, 
 hints = @QueryHint(name = "org.hibernate.callableFunction", value = "true"),
 parameters = {
        @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, type = String.class)
}
```

)

or

```
@Transactional
public Optional<ManagerSummaryEntity> getManagerP2PSummary(EntityManager entityManager, String collectorId) {
    try {
        StoredProcedureQuery query = entityManager.createNamedStoredProcedureQuery("getManagerP2PSummary");
        query.setParameter(2, collectorId);
        query.setHint("org.hibernate.callableFunction", true);
        List<ManagerSummaryEntity> entities = (List<ManagerSummaryEntity>) query.getResultList();
        if (query.execute()) {
            return Optional.of(entities.get(0));
        }
        return Optional.empty();
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}
```

...